# Take picture and Save picture after button is pressed

Tags: java, android, camera, save, capture

Need help on creating a method that will capture a picture, and a method that will save it if a button is pressed.

Currently, the camera is being displayed inside a TextureView as soon as the app starts and I am struggling to find a way to capture and save pictures.

It doesn't really matter if it captures from screen or from the actual phone camera.

Github: https://github.com/Chalikov/group26/tree/experimental

Thank you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 200;
    public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private static final String TAG = "AndroidCameraApi";
    private static final SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 270);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
    }

    protected CameraDevice cameraDevice;
    protected CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSessions;
    protected CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
    private Button takePictureButton;
    private Button retryButton;
    private Button acceptButton;
    private TextureView textureView;
    private String cameraId;
    private Size imageDimension;


    TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            //open your camera here
            openCamera();
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            // Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
        }
    };
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private Uri file;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            //This is called when the camera is open
            Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
            cameraDevice = camera;
            createCameraPreview();
        }
        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            cameraDevice.close();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private View view;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.texture);
        assert textureView != null;
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_takepicture);
        assert takePictureButton != null;
        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
                takePictureButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                retryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_retry);
                acceptButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_analyze);
                retryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                acceptButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                retryButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        createCameraPreview();
                        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        acceptButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        takePictureButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });
                retryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //SHOW the button


                acceptButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        createCameraPreview();
                        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        acceptButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        takePictureButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
                acceptButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //SHOW the button
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageURI(file);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }
    protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    protected void takePicture() {

    }

    protected void savePicture() {

    }

//    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
//        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
//                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");
//
//        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
//            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
//                return null;
//            }
//        }
//
//        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
//        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
//                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
//    }

    protected void createCameraPreview() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(height, width);

            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
            cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    //The camera is already closed
                    if (null == cameraDevice) {
                        return;
                    }
                    // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                    cameraCaptureSessions = cameraCaptureSession;
                    updatePreview();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
    protected void updatePreview() {
        if(null == cameraDevice) {
            Log.e(TAG, "updatePreview error, return");
        }
        captureRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        try {
            cameraCaptureSessions.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void closeCamera() {
        if (null != cameraDevice) {
            cameraDevice.close();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }
        if (null != imageReader) {
            imageReader.close();
            imageReader = null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                // close the app
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        takePictureButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
        startBackgroundThread();
        if (textureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera();
        } else {
            textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        retryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        acceptButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Log.e(TAG, "onPause");
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
        closeCamera();
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.project26.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/texture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_takepicture"
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/camera_button"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_retry"
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/retry"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_analyze"
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="79dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/analyze"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|bottom"
            android:background="#4D000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:text="Gallery"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/camera_menu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                android:text="Camera"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>






</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what error you getting please add LogCat here so all can understand your issue.

Comment: I receive no error. This code works, it displays the camera properly. I only need to make it capture and save pictures.

Comment: Check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LCnoVqQ6N4&t=317s&list=LLdnA00rqVsAZwIxN0koRjsw&index=13

Answer (score 0):

//Modify Id and names according to your project.
//below onclick listener takes pic

```
Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);


           }
    });
```

//override onPictureTaken method, write the below code that saves it to a file.

```
 File pictureFile = PATHOFYOURLOCATION;
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
     fos.write(data);
     Log.d(TAG, "written");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved in "+pictureFile,    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     fos.close();
```

Comment: here i have used a jpeg picture call back. hence the third parameter is passed with that picture call back in takePicture.